# Flutter Error: Getter not found: 'wordPair' in english_words.dart package

Tags: flutter, dart

i recently started learning flutter. I was working on the 'package:english_words/english_words.dart' package. I have successfully imported it by modifying the pubspec.yaml file by adding 'english_words: ^3.1.0 inside dependencies and on the main.dart file `child:Text(wordPair.asPascalCase)` is throwing an error. The output I got after running it is :

> Compiler message:
>   lib/main.dart:17:23: Error: Getter not found: 'wordPair'.
>
> Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
>   build failed.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>     Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

and here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text(wordPair.asPascalCase),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my english.dart file is

```
/// Support for working with English text.
library english_words;

export 'src/syllables.dart';
export 'src/word_pair.dart';
export 'src/words/adjectives.dart';
export 'src/words/all.dart';
export 'src/words/nouns.dart';
```

Comment: can you show us your `english_words.dart` file ?

Comment: So `word_pair.dart` contains an `asPascalCase` method ? How is it structured ?

Answer (score 3):

This file comes from the flutter package, you won't have to modify it.

```
library english_words;

export 'src/syllables.dart';
export 'src/word_pair.dart';
export 'src/words/adjectives.dart';
export 'src/words/all.dart';
export 'src/words/nouns.dart';
```

The problem is the understanding of the `english_words` package. Using `wordPair` makes no sense since you didn't declared it.

You can't access the `asPascalCase` getter with a static instance of `WordPair`. So you will have to create an instance of `WordPair` and then use the `pascalCase` getter.

```
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

var wordpair = WordPair("first,", "second");    
String pascalCase = wordpair.asPascalCase;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. The problem was the `const` in the `body`. It works when i removed it and inserted your `pascalCase` variable.

Answer (score 2):

The working code for this question is also available [here](https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/b3293b5bb0c0187bdbe8112f7759f4d75f4c040a/startup_namer/step2_use_package/lib/main.dart)